# Make Global Action Layout field required only for certain users

Tags: administration, admin, global-actions

Title of the question is self-explanatory, almost.

When user creates a new contact via new button on contact page, there are certain field required for this user.
However, when the same user created a contact via global action called "New Contact". this field is not appears to be as not required.

I know that I can make this field required. But then it'll be required for every user.

How can I make this field required in global action only for one specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Salesforce provides an out-of-the-box way to directly make fields required for certain users in a Global Action Layout.

To achieve this functionality, you can consider using a combination of custom components and custom validation. Below is a high-level outline of how you can approach this:

1. Create a Custom Lightning Component: Build a custom Lightning
   component that represents your Global Action Layout. This component
   will include the field and any other necessary fields.
2. Implement Validation Logic: Within the Lightning component's
   controller or helper, implement the validation logic that checks
   whether the field should be required for the current user.

Comment: A screenflow would be another option